# Can't Insert information into database

Tags: php, mysqli, upload, insert

Hi i have created a simple insert into database function where the student enters his/her information and upload their document into the database,but nothing gets inserted into the database only the files which were uploaded appears on the upload file but not on the database.

html code:

```
<form  accept-charset="utf-8"  action="page.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="wb_Form1" name="form" method="post"  data-toggle="validator" role="form" >
<label>Student Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="stu_name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Name"/><br /><br />



<label>Student Email :</label>
<input type="email" name="stu_email" id="email" required="required" placeholder="john123@gmail.com"/><br/><br />
<label>Student City :</label>


<select name="stu_city">



<option value="works">test</option>

<option value="works3">test</option>



</select>

<label>Image:</label><input type="file" name="image">


<input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit"/><br />

</form>
```

php Code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$servername = "localhost";

$username = "root";

$password = "";

$dbname = "test";



$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);



if ($conn->connect_error) {

die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

}

  $fileinfo=PATHINFO($_FILES["image"]["name"]);


$newFilename=$fileinfo['filename'] ."_". time() . "." . $fileinfo['extension'];



move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $newFilename);
$location="upload/" . $newFilename;



$sql = "INSERT INTO students (student_name, student_email, student_city,img_location)




VALUES ('".$_POST["stu_name"]."','".$_POST["stu_email"]."','".$_POST["stu_city"]."','".$_POST["location"]."')";

header('location:index.php');

}

?>
```

[file hierarchy:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIdIS.jpg)

[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM0rJ.jpg)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please use prepared statements. It'll really help. Mysqli supports it.  What you currently have is beyond risky, so the fact that it doesn't save anything is a blessing. Also the reason it doesn't work is simply because you never executed the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the query. All you have is basically a string.  As per my comment,  you need to use prepared statements. Your code is risky. Also you are inserting the wrong variable for the file location. use the `$location` variable  But to make it insert,  add this

```
$conn->query($sql);
```

Using prepared statements, do this

```
// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO students (student_name, student_email, student_city,img_location) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)");//prepares the query. This returns true/false
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $_POST["stu_name"], $_POST["stu_email"], $_POST["stu_city"],$location);//bind the variables to placeholders to prevent SQL injections
if($stmt->execute() === TRUE){//check if everything went well(executed!)
  echo 'Record Saved';
} else {
  echo 'Error BEcause '.$stmt->error;//get error if something went wrong
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment i will make sure to use prepared statments...i added the query and the data got inserted but the upload file was not inserted into the database

Comment: thank you so much it worked ...for sure i will have to use prepared statments thank you so much

Comment: Ok no problem ..i just want to ask what is the "ssss" for

Comment: The "ssss" denotes that there are four string variables to bind.  i donates that it is integer and d donates that it is double

Answer (score 1):

You didn't execute the query. You just made the query.

NB: A better way to do this will be 'prepared' statement than creating your own query. That will save you from SQL injection and accidental breaking of the query.

Check this out:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your connection, `$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);` and after your $sql is `mysqli_query($conn, $sql);`and you can now do some redirection.

Comment: You don't need to do this.  You can either do it the procedural way or object oriented way.  The OP has chosen the latter. The only needed is to execute the query.  That and fixing the security vulnerabilities

Comment: Well, I agree with you. :)